# centos 6.4 php-fpm install

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, php-fpm, centos6.4

I've bought a VPS from a hosting provider and I want to set it up.
The server is a CentOS-6.4 and the provider installed WHM on it, so it has `apache` installed as well.

I have 3 IPs available and I managed to install `nginx` and make it listen on one of the IPs, while `apache` still responds to the first IP and WHM/CPanel works fine.

My issue is with getting `nginx` to function properly. It works fine serving HTML content, but for PHP it needs `php-fpm` or similar to work.

I've read countless blog posts about how to get this to work and they all say: "add the `epel.repo` and `remi.repo`, set priorities and `yum install php-fpm` and whatever extension you might need.

The problem is when I try to `yum install`, I get:

```
No package php-fpm available.
No package php-cli available.
No package php-mysql available.
No package php-gd available.
No package php-imap available.
No package php-ldap available.
No package php-odbc available.
No package php-pear available.
No package php-xml available.
No package php-xmlrpc available.
No package php-magickwand available.
No package php-magpierss available.
No package php-mbstring available.
No package php-mcrypt available.
No package php-mssql available.
No package php-shout available.
No package php-snmp available.
No package php-soap available.
No package php-tidy available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Any clues as to why it's not working?

Comment: what us output of "yum search php"

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LAXPHH0g

Comment: instead of manually going through installation php-fpm+nginx, you should try this:
http://applications.cpanel.net/cpxstack-the-complete-nginx-php-fpm-stack-on-cpanel/

Comment: will i be able to use varnish with this ? i tried using cpxstack but had some issues with the fpt accounts after installing and thought i'd do the install from scrathc

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem would be solved using the command:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-fpm
```

to install php-fpm, if you've added the repo previously.

Comment: I've enabled both the epel and remi repos through their respective config files. I've set 'enabled=1'. I've also tried your approach at first. still no luck. It's strange though that 'yum search php-fpm' returns no results.